# Can you update an object based on the external Id of a lookup in Talend?

Tags: integration, talend

I have created some jobs in Talend in order to retrieve some information from from a DB, transform it and upsert it into Salesforce. I am trying to update OrderItem records based on the external ID of their related Product2 object. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Is there a way to limit a Salesforce query based on one field of the input DB (Input DB records have 1 field "ExternalId__c" from object Product2, I want to use a tSalesforceInput but limit the search for that field on each iteration, so you don't search for all the records in your instance)?